# Выбор оптимального языка и СУБД

Tags: база-данных, веб-программирование

Кто из опытных здесь программистов с большим опытом могут сказать какой язык из данных будет более оптимальнее для написания крупного веб-приложения, допустим как Google(конечно взмахнул, но все же).

1. LISP
2. PHP
3. PYTHON
4. PERL
5. ASP
6. RUBY

и выбор оптимальных СУБД:

1. MYSQL
2. MSQL
3. ORACLE
4. POSTGRESQL
5. MONGODB
6. ЛИНТЕР

Нужно выбрать отсюда 1 самый производительный язык программирования, а так же безопасную и производительную СУБД.

Comment: давно ли это asp стал языком программирования а Google - веб-приложением?

Comment: большой опыт подсказывает, что на любом языке и субд можно написать как большую систему, так и маленькую, как безопасную и производительную, так и дырявую и тормозную. обычно дело в прослойке между креслом и клавиатурой.

Comment: DreamChild я просил писать знающих людей а вы даже и не знаете много а точнее самого простого, http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C2%E5%E1-%EF%F0%EE%E3%F0%E0%EC%EC%E8%F0%EE%E2%E0%ED%E8%E5 почитайте там ясно написано К серверным языкам программирования можно отнести: PHP, Perl, Python, Ruby, любой .NET язык программирования (технология ASP.NET), Java, Groovy.

Comment: @Дмитрий Астафьев учитывая, что я работаю с этим самым ASP три года, с вашей стороны довольно опрометчиво заявлять, что я не знаю, что это такое. Так вот ASP - это не язык программирования. Подучите матчасть, прежде чем кого-то упрекать в незнании

Comment: А есть еще такие языки как DirectX и OpenGL, на них игры пишут. Есть еще язык ajax, на нем сайты пишут. И самый популярный на хэшкоде новый язык - это xcode. На нем пишут в эппле, айфоне и айподе (или как там правильно айпаде?).

Comment: Как гугл...? А как это? Нужны четкие требования. Кстати посмотрите в сторону node.js + mongo (+memcache)

Comment: @Дмитрий Астафьев - берите тот язык и базу, которую Вы знаете. Я к примеру брал бы Perl/Python + MySQL (и только потому, что с указанного списка я их знаю наиболее хорошо). Писал бы на них прототип, смотрел. Если проект взлетит, тогда часть кода возможно была бы переписана на с++/java/postgre.

Comment: @Дмитрий Астафьев если вы выбираете язык, с помощью которого впоследствии будете зарабатывать на жизнь, то критерий "самый производительный" тут вряд ли должен быть на первом плане (самый производительный и вовсе ассемблер, но второй фейсбук на нем вряд ли напишешь), тут важнее другие характеристики - число вакансий, сложность освоения, перспективы на рынке и тд. Из указанного вами списка вряд ли можно выбрать язык, который на голову выше всех остальных, поэтому однозначно правильного ответа на ваш вопрос быть не может

Comment: @Дмитрий Астафьев Вам  @KoVadim уже написал -- который знаете. Самым первым крупным web-приложением был ViaWeb. Он был написан на CommomLisp. Приобретён Yahoo, назван Yahoo Store, а некоторое время спустя переписан на C++. (Причина не в производительности, а в сопровождении. У яхи, видимо, были проблемы с наймом лиспоидов)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такая штука, как Node.js. На нем можно написать все что на PHP и то, что на PHP нельзя вообще сделать. Но для этого надо очень хорошо знать JavaScript. Может это то, что ты ищешь?

Comment: Ну все, пхпкапец, рубикапец и питонкапец. Что именно можно сделать на ноде, чего нельзя сделать на других языках?

Comment: Веб-сокеты на PHP можно сделать?

Comment: Вебсокеты - это протокол, их на чем угодно можно сделать, что умеет работать с простыми сокетами. http://socketo.me/

Comment: @Fike да на ноде, можно сделать. а именно - писать бэкенд и фронтенд  на одном языке. При этом не скрывая клиентскую часть за ,например, ryby синтаксисом. 
Я правда не знаю плюс это или минус, но теперь школоте не придется учить два языка чтобы говнокодить.

да и асинхронку на php писать, то еще удовольствие. :)

Comment: @eicto проще всего будет ответить, что автор вообще про асинхронность не заикался

> Я правда не знаю плюс это или минус, но теперь школоте не придется учить два языка чтобы говнокодить.

(node.)js is the new php

Answer (score 1):

php и mysql сейчас распространены. На них держится очень много проектов.
Да и уроков предостаточно для решения любой задачи.

Comment: PHP я знаю с MYSQL ищу что то более лучшее для серьезных целей, читал и говорили что PHP - детская игрушка.

Comment: @Дмитрий Астафьев, несмотря на общий уровень использования PHP и многочисленные PHP-палки в колесах, такой подход в корне неверен. Посмотрите на Symfony, на этой штуке можно в космос летать и CRM'ы строить, она изначально написана под гигантский масштаб.

Comment: Эм...а можно о палках поподробнее. А то у меня CMS система написана на PHP+MySQL, может мне стоит ее переписать пока они еще в бете?=)

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/142140/

Comment: @Fike, отлично! Особенно понравилось:

    PHP — это комьюнити любителей. Очень мало людей, которые его создают, работают над ним или пишут код на нём, вообще представляют, что они делают(о, дорогой читатель, вы конечно редкое исключение!). Те, кто начинают что-то понимать, сколонны уходить на другие платформы, снижая среднюю компетенцию общего числа. Видите, вот она самая большая проблема PHP: это абсолютно точно слепец ведомый слепцом.

Comment: Ну если честно, то все написанное в посте, просто излияная души программиста который привык кодить на другом языке и пересел потом на PHP. Все уж слишком подтянуто за уши.

Answer (score 1):

Python.У него интерфей к PostgreSQL и MongoDB.

Comment: ну надо же!

Comment: А у других языков его нет... как жаль... :)))